# Is it possible to trim tag value before validation in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

The xml looks like:

```
<Asset>
    <NAME>XX905886XX58</NAME>
</Asset>
<Asset>
    <NAME>XX905886XX58             </NAME>
</Asset>`
```

I have validation in my xsd file for duplicated `<NAME>` tag. 
But, in described below XML, i would like to validate `<NAME>` after trimming.
The question: is it possible to trim value before validation? Ho to do it in xsd?

My xsd validation code:

```
<xs:unique name="UniqueAsset">
  <xs:selector xpath="Asset"/>
  <xs:field xpath="NAME"/>
</xs:unique>`
```

**UPDATE**

It works if add to XSD `<xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>`:

```
  <xs:element name="NAME">
    <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the type of the element NAME is derived from xs:token (or anything else with the whitespace facet "collapse"), then the uniqueness test will apply to the value after whitespace-trimming.

Comment: Michael, thank you, it works with `collapse`, but doesn't work with `replace`.